# Koller's dungeon safe

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

There is a safe inside Koller's dungeon located in the gas room and it has a password.

Where do I find the password for that safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the location of the code for the safe is on a [pocket secretary in the sewers under Prague's Davny district](http://guides.gamepressure.com/deusexmankinddivided/guide.asp?ID=37081).

The actual code is:

> 5555. [Found from this page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/deus-ex-mankind-divided/Passwords_and_Keycodes) under the Prague section.

[This guide](http://www.gamecrate.com/5-secret-locations-loot-your-first-few-hours-deus-ex-mankind-divided/14411) says that the safe is also hackable for those who have level 3 security access, or they can also use a multi-tool found earlier. The guide say that:

> in the small medical cooler to the left of his [Koller's] operating chair you'll find a free Multi-Tool just waiting for you to snag.

Comment: @vianna77 I've updated the post and  removed my comments.  Glad I was able to find it!

Comment: Just to complement the answer, as soon you get into the sewer, there is a locked gate with a body behind it. That's where the password is located. To open the gate you can either (A) put one red barrel at the gate and shot until it explodes or (B) in the room where you meet K, jump on the tubes, from the tubes go to the ledge, find the hole in the wall and follow the tunnel.